# Django Model Form using default despite widget specifications?

Tags: python, django

I've defined the following form:

```
from django import forms
from my_app.models import Business


class BusinessNameForm(forms.models.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Business
        fields = ('business_name',)
        widgets = {
        'text': forms.fields.TextInput(attrs={
            'placeholder': 'Enter a business name',
            'class': 'form-control input-lg',
            }),
        }
```

However, when I try to see what the form would look like:

```
f = BusinessName()
f.as_p()
```

It gives me the following HTML:

```
'<p><label for="id_business_name">Business name:</label> <input id="id_business_name" maxlength="100" name="business_name" type="text" /></p>'
```

Why isn't it setting the placeholder and class attributes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're supposed to use the field name as the key in the widgets dict.

```
widgets = {
    'business_name': forms.fields.TextInput(attrs={
        'placeholder': 'Enter a business name',
        'class': 'form-control input-lg',
    }),
}
```

See [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields).